# AudioTrack created from AudioStreamDestinationNode does not stop when all source audio tracks are stopped

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediastream

I merged AudioTracks from getDisplayMedia(system audio) and getUserMedia(microphone) and created a new audio track from them using AudioContext. When I stopped each of the source Audio tracks, the new audio tracks for MediaStreamDestinationNode(outcome of merging two source audio tracks) does not get stopped.

My questions are:

1. I wonder if it is possible to bubble up ended event of source audio tracks to new audio tracks merged by AudioContext.
2. Just curious if there is a purpose of keeping MediaStreamDestinatioNode's audio track alive when all source audio tracks are stopped.

```
                var screen = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                    video:{
                        width:{
                            ideal:1280, 
                            max:1280
                        }, 
                        height:{
                            ideal:720, 
                            max:720
                        }
                    }, 
                    audio:{
                        echoCancellation: false,
                        noiseSuppression: true,
                        sampleRate: 44100,
                    }
                }).then(async (stream)=>{
                    const ctx = new AudioContext();
                    mediaStream_01 = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: {deviceId: "default"}});
                    mediaStream_01.getAudioTracks()[0].onended = function () {console.log('mic audiostream ended')};
                    stream.getAudioTracks()[0].onended = function (){console.log('screenshare audio stream ended')};
                    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = function (){console.log('screenshare video stream ended')};
                    mediaStream_02 = stream;
                    audioIn_01 = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream_01);
                    audioIn_02 = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream_02);

                    dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
                    audioIn_01.connect(dest);
                    audioIn_02.connect(dest);

                    newStream = new MediaStream([...stream.getVideoTracks(), ...dest.stream.getAudioTracks()]);
                    newStream.getAudioTracks()[0].onended = function () {console.log('merged audio tracks ended')};
var recorder = new MediaRecorder(newStream);
```

When I manually stop screen share and default microphone(disconnect), it fires the onended events for the source audio tracks, but it does not fire the onended event for MediaStreamDestinationNode's audio track. Because new audio track does not get stopped, in turn MediaRecorder continues to record the empty stream, and it has to be stopped manually.

Comment: Why would it fire this event? You AudioContext is still up and running. For all the `MediaStreamDestinationNode` knows, it can still very well get connected to anything after that point.

Comment: @Kaiido I actually want to record the newly created media stream with MediaRecorder. I edited my question to include that point. Normally MediaRecorder would stop recording when media tracks that it has been recording are stopped. But, in my case because newly created media stream does not get stopped, it has to be stopped manually. I reckon I can put recorder.stop() within onended event source MediaTracks, but I would like to know if there is a canonical way to close AudioStreamDestinationNode from detecting closing of its source media tracks.

Comment: @Kaiido I think your comment already answers my second question. So it is designed to reuse MediaStreamDestinationNode after its original media stream sources been ended.